# Collaborative development for Android

Tags: android, collaborative

Is there any **collaborative development**  site specifically having Android application developers collaborating?

I have looked into the [GITHUB](https://github.com/). But dint got anything usefull.

Any pointers will be helpfull.

Thanks,
Gamdroid

Comment: Well code.google.com is what I like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each project has its own means of collaboration. Your best bet is to find a project you want to work on, visit its irc channel or join its mailing lists, and engage its community.

Even when you work with others on open source projects, you still do the majority of the work on your own. Usually collaboration only goes as far as submitting patches to the project managers.

If you're looking for a place to get help in real-time, you might try Stackoverflow chat or #android-dev on freenode irc.